# What Container to use to keep an index updated automatically?

Tags: java, swing, collections, indexing, tablemodel

Following situation: I need a container for data with a rowindex. Currently we use a normal ArrayList within tablemodels and update tablerownumbers by hand (with crazy algorithms, to keep them updated after adding, deleting, moving data within that container.

After finding the third bug updating these tablerows I thought about finally using a different container to keep them updated automatically. My first thought was using a LinkedList. Only thing I dislike is, that within a LinkedList I cant move items without deleting/readding them, but still seems satisfying.

The Rowheader itself is an own table and needs to be updated for every event, to keep both in sync.

[image: RowHeader Example]

Just wondering, if you can recommend alternatives. So I am curious what kind of container would you use?

thanks,
ymene

Comment: Not really sure why you would need crazy algorithms in this case. Creating a `TableModel` based on a `List` and keeping them in sync sounds rather straight-forward (if you have a `List` which fires events, or another hook to detect changes in the `List`)

Comment: maybe I overstated theses algorithms a bit. I just thought it might be easier to use an container, which already has an index. We indeed have a list, which fires these events. So you would go the classic way and update the rowheader with receiving theses events to keep them in sync?

Comment: Are you using `DefaultTableModel` or `AbstractTableModel`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm not sure I fully understand the question. But supposing you have a `List<Person>`, and you need a table displaying the row number, the person first name, and the person last name, you don't need any index in the Person or even in the list to do that:

```
public class PersonTableModel extends AbstractTableModel {

    private List<Person> persons;

    public int getRowCount() {
        return persons.size();
    }

    public int getColumnCount() {
        return 3;
    }

    public Object getValueAt(int row, int col) {
        if (col == 0) {
            return row + 1;
        }
        else if (col == 1) {
            return persons.get(row).getFirstName();
        }
        else {
            return persons.get(row).getLastName();
        }
    }
    ...
}
```

An ArrayList would be much more efficient than a LinkedList, since indexed access is O(1) rather than O(n) for a LinkedList.

Comment: I noticed my question didnt really seem to point out were I am aiming at, sorry for that. The table itself is already fine (i think), but I have an extra table for the tablerowheader (for displaying reasons, like scrolling), which I need to display for the user. This is also the header, where move operations are done with via drag and drop. I generally have to sync these two tables. So my question was all about how to organize these tablerownumbers. I added a picture, which hopefully explains it a bit better then i do.

Comment: Your rowHeader table model should listen to the events fired by the main table model, and adapt its content based on the new row count of the main table model. But I don't see why anything other than its row count should change. And its getValueAt() method should be similar to the one in my answer, for the column at index 0.